# How to work with python 2 and 3

Tags: python

I found that some libs depend python2 and some libs work on python3. 
I know there is a lib that can port code from python 2 to python 3. I am not sure if it has more easy way to make these libs work together. 
How can I use these libs? Thanks a lot

EDIT: to make the question more specific. 
I want to write python script to copy changelist from perforce and commit them into git. So I want to use both [GitPython](https://github.com/gitpython-developers/GitPython) and P4Python. [GitPython](https://github.com/gitpython-developers/GitPython) can only work on python 2 (although evaluate python 3.3 compatibility is its current goal) while P4Python can only work on python 3.

How can I make this work?

Comment: `import `[`six`](http://pythonhosted.org/six/)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11372190/python-2-and-python-3-dual-development

Comment: @tripleee with six, I can write code that can run on python 2 and 3. But how can I make two dependence libs (one needs python2, the other needs python3) work together?

Comment: I need my code work with gitdb which needs python2 and python-perforce which needs python3.

Answer (score 2):

There are many tools and tricks to port python 2.x to python 3.x and to write code compatible with both version.

You will find a dedicated [Howto](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/pyporting.html) on that subject in Python 3 documentation. Some referenced tools:

- [2to3](http://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html): to convert from Python2 to Python3
- caniusepython3 ([command-line tool](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/caniusepython3), [web app](https://caniusepython3.com/): to control dependencies
- [six](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/six): low level project to help writing 2-3 compatible code
- [modernize](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/python-modernize): to help porting existing code to six

And last but not least `__future__` is a must in that context, at least the famous:

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

that allows using the `print()` function from Python3 under Python2

But if you want to do serious things, read the whole Howto.

Answer (score 1):

*Most* python2.x projects can be made to work with python3 using the [2to3](https://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html) tool which typically comes bundled with your python3.x installation.

As noted in the comments, if you're interested in *developing* code that can be used (out of the box) on both python2.x and python3.x, the third party package [`six`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/six) contains lots of useful utilities for writing backward and forward compatible code.  It doesn't help you run somebody else's code though :-).