# Can Python code satisfy both 2.7.x and 3.4.x requirements?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I wrote some code in Python 2.7.2 and now I may need to switch to 3.4.3, but my code breaks (simply `print` statements right now, but who knows what else). Is it possible to write the syntax in such a way that it will be compliant with both 2.7.2 and 3.4.3?

I am just starting out with Python and don't want to build habits with one flavor and then have to relearn things with another version later.

Comment: There are tools like [2to3](https://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html) or [six](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/six).

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/3/howto/pyporting.html. *"and who knows what else"* - see https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html. Unless you have some good reason otherwise (e.g. a library you *must have* that's not 3.x compliant), just use 3.x.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python 2 and Python 3 dual development](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11372190/python-2-and-python-3-dual-development)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but depending on your code. You have lot of options:

- Use [`from __future__ import ...`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/__future__.html) (making your code work with Python 2 & 3 - see e.g. [this](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/200910/running_the_same_code_on_python_2x_and_3x.html) and [this](http://www.dwheeler.com/essays/python3-in-python2.html))
- Use [`modernize`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/modernize)
- Use [`six`](http://pythonhosted.org/six/)

Comment: So as I understand it, there are tools I can use to change one form of the code to another form automatically ... but I was originally asking if I could adopt a style of programming for which it will always be both 2.7.x and 3.4.x compliant.

Comment: No, please read all the info we gave you, including also the link @jonrsharpe gave. It's not only about tools, is all about what you want to do: works with both versions, drop python2, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Python code can be compatible with both Python 2 and 3.

There are 3 options how to do it:

- keep the **source code itself compatible with** both **Python 2 and 3**; this is the most used way
- use **separate code** for Python 2 and 3; generally not very useful, but maybe acceptable for some low-level code. For example [CherryPy wsgiserver](https://github.com/cherrypy/cherrypy/tree/master/cherrypy/wsgiserver) (notice the files `wsgiserver2.py` and `wsgiserver3.py`).
- write code in either Python 2 or Python 3 and use automatic tool like 2to3 or 3to2 for **translation** to the other version.

When Python 3 was first released the 2to3 way was the preferred one. You can find this in [What’s New In Python 3.0](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#porting-to-python-3-0): *"It is not recommended to try to write source code that runs unchanged under both Python 2.6 and 3.0."* But times have changed since then. Some things were introduced that made writing code for both Python 2 and 3 much easier - for example the `u""` syntax in Python 3.3. Also the tool 3to2 did not get much updates since 2010...

When writing code that works unchanged on both Python 2 and 3 some **compatibility code** with few simple `if`s may be needed; look for example at [flask/_compat.py](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/blob/master/flask/_compat.py). If this isn't sufficient then use [six](http://pythonhosted.org/six/).

Some resources how to write code working on both Python 2 and 3:

- http://lucumr.pocoo.org/2011/1/22/forwards-compatible-python/
- http://python-future.org/compatible_idioms.html#essential-syntax-differences
- http://python3porting.com/noconv.html
- https://docs.python.org/3/howto/pyporting.html

The Python 2/3 problem applies mostly for libraries, shared code and Python 2 projects that are being upgraded to Python 3. If you are starting a project that is not a library then just go with **Python 3** if possible.

Answer (score 0):

There are already some great answers above. A quick fix for your print problems would be to make use of the **future** module which backports some Python 3 features to Python 2.

I'd recommend as a minimum writing you're Python 2.7 code with the new print function. To do this import the new print function from **future**. i.e.

`from __future__ import print_function`

You will now get syntax errors in Python 2 using print as:

`print x`

and will now have to do:

`print(x)`

Other solutions like 2to3 and six exist, but these might be a bit complicated at the moment, especially as you are learning Python.