# vncdotool support on python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, vnc

looks like the best option to vnc from Python is vncdotool module. I've been using it with Python2 without any problem. Now I am moving toward to Python3. It seems not working at all on my Mac. Here is the problem.

after creating venv and install pip3 install vncdotool. I get immediate error when running the vncdo command. It says "print data". looks like it is running Python2 code "print 'xxx' vs print('xxx')"

```
(vnc) mac:vnc user$ vncdo
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/Documents/code/vnc/bin/vncdo", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('vncdotool==0.10.0', 'console_scripts', 'vncdo')()
  File "/Users/user/Documents/code/vnc/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 565, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/Users/user/Documents/code/vnc/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2631, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/Users/user/Documents/code/vnc/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2291, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/Users/user/Documents/code/vnc/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2297, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "/Users/user/Documents/code/vnc/lib/python3.6/site-packages/vncdotool/command.py", line 79
    print data
             ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'
(vnc) Mac:vnc user$
```

when I run python3 in interactive mode, and trying to import the api module. I got another error saying Queue is not available.

```
(vnc) Mac:vnc user$ python
Python 3.6.1 (default, Apr  4 2017, 09:40:21)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.38)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from vncdotool import api
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/user/Documents/code/rdpvnc/lib/python3.6/site-        packages/vncdotool/api.py", line 8, in <module>
    import Queue
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Queue'
>>>
```

I checked the [github page](https://github.com/sibson/vncdotool) seeing that there is indeed python3 support. however, there is not much info anywhere on internet.

```
setup.py    added python 3  8 months ago
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python 2 and Python 3 dual development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11372190/python-2-and-python-3-dual-development)

Comment: Ivan - Python2 is from the stand macos package. I install Python3 with homebrew on my mac. Do you mean Python2 and Python3 can't be coexist?

Comment: The suggested duplicate has hints how to fix that module so it runs in both py2 and py3.

Comment: Hi Ivan, not sure if Im getting the idea correctly. I am not looking for making my code to run on both py2 and py3 env. I want to use the vncdotool module in Py3. the error I got looks like the module doesn't run on py3 env. but the official web saying the vncdotool does support py3. i'm trying to get a Windows machine to test if it is mac specific but it's been taking very long time to install the VC++ buildtools which is required when installing twisted module for vncdotool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The module, as you have it, doesn't support Python 3 - the code in your stacktrace is clearly py2-only. The fact that the developer added "Python 3" to `setup.py`'s metadata doesn't mean that the support is complete - especially considering the fact that the last release (as of this writing) was earlier - [in Mar 2016](https://github.com/sibson/vncdotool/releases/tag/v0.10.0).

You can install the `git` `HEAD` version of the module and see if the support works in it. At least, the `print` statements in [`command.py`](https://github.com/sibson/vncdotool/blob/master/vncdotool/command.py) that your program chokes on have been fixed.

```
pip install git+https://github.com/sibson/vncdotool.git
```

The suggested duplicate, [Python 2 and Python 3 dual development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11372190/python-2-and-python-3-dual-development), suggests how to fix the code so that it runs in both Python 2 and 3. If the support is incomplete, you can offer the rest of the fixes to the maintainer as a pull request.

Comment: thanks a lot Ivan. it works now by installing the git directly as you suggested.